# Mask values in a pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I need to replace values in a dataframe that are lower than a certain value for NaNs.

For example, suppose I need to replace all values higher than 100 for NaN

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,250,480],
               'b':[60,51,101],
               'c':[15,689,1]})
```

would become:

```
({'a':[1,NaN,NaN],
  'b':[60,51,NaN],
  'c':[15,NaN,1]})
```

Which should be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.mask(df > 100)

df = df.where(df <= 100)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df > 100, np.nan, df), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
print (df)
     a     b     c
0  1.0  60.0  15.0
1  NaN  51.0   NaN
2  NaN   NaN   1.0
```

Fast comparison (depends of data):

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [104]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.where(df > 100, np.nan, df), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
The slowest run took 4.37 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 683 µs per loop

In [105]: %timeit df[:] = np.where(df.values <= 100, df.values, np.nan)
__main__:257: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
The slowest run took 17.24 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 957 µs per loop

In [106]: %timeit df.mask(df > 100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.56 ms per loop

In [107]: %timeit df.where(df <= 100)
The slowest run took 8.01 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.84 ms per loop

In [108]: %timeit df[df<100]
The slowest run took 5.57 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.89 ms per loop
```

Comment: Which solution is better yours or coldspeed, can you please explain.

Comment: @RaoSahab When a better answer cannot be determined, upvote all answers and flip a coin to decide what to select ;-)

Comment: Both answers are very good. I think the numpy version _may_ be slightly faster because less overhead in terms of vectorisation, but it depends on data. Best is to time it.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I knew that both were good, but question was more on complexity side. But thanks for the explanations. +1 to both of you as thanks.

Comment: @RaoSahab - Thank you for upvotes to both answers :)

Answer (score 3):

`np.where` with in-place update;

```
df[:] = np.where(df.values <= 100, df.values, np.nan)
df

     a     b     c
0  1.0  60.0  15.0
1  NaN  51.0   NaN
2  NaN   NaN   1.0
```

Comment: Can you check comment under my answer? What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

The shortest one would be

```
df[df<100]
```